# Synchronize between MS Access and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ms-access, synchronization

### The problem

My company is forced to migrate our MS Access 2003 databases to SQL Server 2012. Many of our web applications use a direct connection to different MS Access 2003 databases, these databases have also different relations among each other.

We want to migrate/build our old web applications (classic ASP) to new web applications (ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework), one by one (within a few years) and not all at once in one big bang.

### The requirements

- the old web applications should keep working with their old MS Access 2003 databases;
- the new web applications should only work with SQL Server 2012;
- the data between the MS Access 2003 databases and SQL Server should be synchronized bidirectional (when someone updates a record in any MS Access 2003 database, it should be updated in the SQL Server 2012 database as well and vice versa).

I was looking around for a while in books and the internet, I found a lot of out dated information about; synchronizing between MS Access and SQL Server, but still not any valuable source and/or solution. My conclusion at this moment is; that there is no solution out of the box available for this problem.

### Maybe a possible solution

Maybe we should build a custom service (RESTful API) that will be used for our new web applications (which are forced to use the Entity Framework). This custom service will also synchronize between MS Access and SQL Server:

- by writing duplicate queries (double entities)? one for the MS Access database and the other for the SQL Server database.
- and polling the mutations from MS Access databases to the SQL Server databases

### The question

My question is, is it possible to synchronize between MS Access and SQL Server? If not, what would be a good solution in this case?

All advice, feedback, comments, experiences etc. are welcome! Thank you in advance!

Comment: This topic is massive to say the least. The amount of effort required to keep these in synch is going to be staggering. This question is really considered off topic because it is entirely too broad and it is also primarily opinion based. There just isn't a "correct" answer for this.

Comment: Thats why I ask for feedback from people with experience with these large scaled problems, and ofcourse for the people who are interessed to give feedback :) I appreciate all opinions and advice!

Comment: Synchronizing would be painful to implement and test, and would be prone to many problems.  You might consider designing the new apps so that you can switch them from using the Access DBs to using the SQL DBs by simply changing a setting in web.config.  Have them use the Access databases until you have all of the apps re-coded, then you migrate all of the databases and flip the switch in a one-time cutover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to not even try bidirectional synchronizing large amounts of data.

- Identify "groups" of applications whose databases have no relations with databases of other groups. (*)
- Start with one group, build and test the new applications.
- When done, do one final migration from Access to Sql Server for this group, and switch over.
- Repeat for the next group.

Running both systems in parallel is a bad idea. Seriously.

(*) If you end up with just one group, then so be it.